# Are 10+ year contracts discouraged or prohibited in the NBA?

Tags: basketball, nba, finances

In 2019, Mike Trout signed a 12-year, $430 million contract. This is on the heels of Bryce Harper signing a 13-year, $330 million contract. There have been several 10-year contracts signed by baseball players.

The longest contracts in the NBA during the 2018-2019 season are 5-6 years in length. The [longest contracts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_sports_contracts) in the NBA during the 2000s were 7 years in length.

Are 10+ year contracts discouraged or prohibited in the NBA? If discouraged, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always, you want the fantastic [CBA FAQ](http://www.cbafaq.com/salarycap.htm), in this case, [Question 53 "Is there a limit to the length of a contract?"](http://www.cbafaq.com/salarycap.htm#Q53):

> The maximum years and raises depend on the type of contract, however the "standard" maximum length is four seasons [...] The following are exceptions to the standard:
>
> [ ...a number of exceptions, but the longest is: ]
>
> Extensions (Designated Veterans)  6 [years]

"Why?" is a more complicated question. The maximum contract length was introduced in order to prevent teams crippling their teams for multiple years by being tied into a high-priced contract with a veteran who is years past their prime - see e.g. [Rick DiPietro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rick_DiPietro) for what happens if this kind of restriction doesn't exist.

While the contract length restriction has accomplished that aim, it's also had the effect of moving a lot of power to the players as teams can't lock up their legitimate superstars for long contracts - see in particular LeBron James's multiple moves, and Kevin Durant's move to the Warriors (and his potential leaving).

Comment: Part of limiting contract length may also come from salary caps. Allowing a 20 year contract when a player will never play the length of it distorts the valuations on an annual basis, bypassing cap limits. Any deferred payments need to be accounted for accurately.

Comment: @JonCuster The CBA pretty much covers this with the [Over 38 Rule](http://www.cbafaq.com/salarycap.htm#Q56) - in short, this assumes the players won't play past age 38 and pushes the cap hit into any years before that, no matter how long the actual contract is.

Comment: Fun fact: Magic Johnson signed a 25 year deal with the Lakers in 1981. I've heard it likened to a *de facto* ownership stake. https://www.nytimes.com/1981/06/26/sports/magic-johnson-signs-25-million-contract.html